# Aggregate values in different row based on group

Tags: powerbi, dax

My goal is to aggregate values in a single column based on groups of other columns.

For example my table looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqSRp.jpg

and the desired output would be something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsTnD.jpg

I can do this on the same table or create a new table.

I have attemped this:

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Sheet1 (2)'[Item],
    'Sheet1 (2)'[Name],
    "Total", SUM([Money])
)
```

but the error returned is: *The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.*z

**EDIT**

Ultimately my end goal is to create a calculated column to round the dollar up based on a series of ranges using SWITCH function.

```
=SWITCH(TRUE(),[Money] <= 10, 0, [Money] <= 20, 10)
```

...something like that.

Comment: Power BI will automatically group aggregate values depending on the dimensions you select for a visual. You don't need to create a separate measure to achieve the desired output from your screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, I have a subsequent task to create another calculated column based on the output. Is there a way we can achieve this output using summarizecolumns function?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include detail about your further calculated column?

Comment: I've added the detail, thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok. You don't need all those bells & whistles! You just need a simple measure, I'll include as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a sum of each group rounded down to the nearest 10 using the following:

```
Answer =
FLOOR ( SUM ( 'Sheet1 (2)'[Money] ), 10 )
```

`FLOOR()` takes the Sum of your "Money" column as the first argument, and your required multiple (in this case 10) as the second. `CEILING()` and `MROUND()` can be used alternatively if you want to round up, or to the nearest value.

**EDIT:**

Based on your recent comments, perhaps something like this would be more appropriate:

```
Answer = 
IF(SUM('Sheet1 (2)'[Money]) < 10, 0,
IF(SUM('Sheet1 (2)'[Money]) < 20, 10,
IF(SUM('Sheet1 (2)'[Money]) < 25, 20, BLANK())))
```

`SWITCH` can only be used with constants, so you'll need to chain together some `IF` statements to get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on these functions here! My rounding will be more stringent and often isn't to the 10th place, so this is why I just favor using the switch function. Also, the above does not group the rows as desired, it's just returning the rounded value.

Comment: It groups the rows dynamically, that's the beauty of Power BI! If you view this measure in the context of 'Item' and 'Name', it will group by both. If you just view it in the context of 'Name', it'll aggregate by name. You do not need to 'hard code' specific grouping behaviour to achieve this particular result.

Comment: Could you describe how you would like the rounding to work?

Comment: Aggregated dollar values will be displayed as: 0-9$ = 0$ ; 10-19 = 10; 20-24 = 20; 25-39 = 25; >40 = 40.... soo there's really no logic to it and unfortunately will have to hard code

Comment: I'd question the underlying business requirements that led to that decision and propose a more logical approach to rounding behaviour if it were me..! At any rate, you can still achieve this with a single measure.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your most recent comment.

Comment: Thanks, Rory! You and me both... Still struggling to see how I can make this work though. Using the switch function or the IF statement above alone, when I visualize the table, it's double counting the items (even though it's grouped them together, in it still aggregates the values of the function)

Comment: Use a measure as opposed to a calculated column if possible, otherwise it will 'double count' as you put it.

Comment: Thank you for all the above functions and help around this!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do would be create a simple measure:

```
Total=SUM([Money])
```

Then, you can view this in Power BI by putting the Name on an axis:

Like this...
[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQs9Z.png)

Or this...
[Bar Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqIMj.png)

In Excel, you could use Pivot Tables to show the same thing.

Comment: The problem though is that I need to perform additional measures on that sum column, and it isn't just a matter of visualization.

Comment: In that case, I would try this...

Total by Item by Name :=
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE ( Table1, Table1[Item], Table1[Name], "Total", SUM ( Table1[Money] ) ),
    [Total]
)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be grouping by the columns and it's just aggregating all of the dollar values in the table.

Comment: You will need to add a grouping to whatever visualization you pick.  So, if you want to see by Item and Name, then add those to the table or matrix.  In Excel, you would put the Item and Name in the Pivot Table rows, and the Total in the Values section.  In a Power BI Table visual, you would add Item, Name, and Total into the Values section.

Comment: I saw that you added Edits to you question.  If you want to round after you do the calculation, you can change your SWITCH statement to be a measure (not calculated column ) which references the Total measure (instead of [Money]).